# Checking if elements in array are even and sort them in specific order

Tags: arrays

I've been trying to get my head around this but I can't seem to find a good way to do this, so basically what I'm trying to achieve is sorting array in a way that numbers are sorted for example like this:

```
Array output (unsorted)
7777777777
7777777777
6666666666
6666666666
2222222222

Array output (sorted)
7777777777
6666666666
2222222222
6666666666
7777777777
```

I was thinking about making an array NxN and sort it in a way that if there are like 2 array elements of sevens and sixes it will sort them like

```
7
6
6
7
```

and all odd numbers like in this exemple 2 it will sort them like

```
7
6
2
6
7
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain the rules of your 'sort'.

Comment: once you figure out the rules of that "sorting", it shouldn't be that hard to code up something... and then show the code and ask for further help.

Comment: It looks like you unsorted data is sorted and your sorted data is some kind of mirroring.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes something like that, I should check wether all numbers in array element are equal and if array is symmetric. If they are and it is it should take same elements and put one on the top and one on the bottom and if array element has no other element to pair it with it should place that element to the middle.

Comment: What if there were three of something?

Comment: @NikolaiV. can edit the question and put your clarification about the sorting rule there?

Comment: How should the multiple odd elements in the middle be sorted?

Comment: It looks like you have cases or pattern  
for initial sorted array .  
For example it has odd number of unique items  
and all except one item goes in pairs   
so the one unpaired item must be in the middle .   
If you describe all the corner cases - then you got your algorithm .

Comment: @Don't Panic All should go to the middle, only even elements should be sorted symmetrically

Comment: That question almost sounds like a codegolf puzzle ;)

Comment: Оne way to solve it 
using sorted array 
( and item's frequency map <- overkill ). 
Starting from the smallest element append and prepend 
all items from the sorted list according to their count in the initial array . 
But you still must use some condition to check 
if resulted list is symmetrical 
or can be build from the source array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the values in the array.

```
$values = array_count_values($array);
```

(You can `asort($values);` or `arsort($values);` after this if you want larger groups of even values to be sorted toward the inside or outside of the symmetrical part of the result array. Or if you don't care, don't.)

Build arrays of evens and odds based on those counts.

```
foreach ($values as $value => $count) {
    if ($count % 2) {
        while ($count--) $odds[] = $value;
    } else {
        $count /= 2;  // half the size, so half can go at the beginning and half at the end
        while ($count--) $evens[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Merge the even and odd arrays together to create the result.

```
$result = array_merge($evens, $odds, array_reverse($evens));
```